Is it possible to add trait bound to associated type of supertrait?
This almost works (in nightly): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=332ca47a9d3618a8427ae618f0a8b188
#![feature(non_lifetime_binders)]

trait Foo {}

trait HasAssoc {
    type Assoc<T>;
}

trait HasFooAssoc: for<T> HasAssoc<Assoc<T>: Foo> {}

struct X;
struct Y<T>(T);

impl<T> Foo for Y<T> {}
impl HasAssoc for X {
    type Assoc<T> = Y<T>;
}
impl HasFooAssoc for X {}

I'm trying to define HasFooAssoc, which is a HasAssoc where Assoc: Foo is known to hold. From my reading of the errors, it seems like the problem is that for<T> has to also hold for T: ?Sized, and I'm not syntactically allowed to type for<T: Sized> (T actually should be Sized for my use case).
Note that if the Foo bound is hardcoded into HasAssoc, there is no problem: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e6f7ec36babd27e0e160c023052be4c3
trait Foo {}

trait HasAssoc {
    type Assoc<T>: Foo;
}

struct X;
struct Y<T>(T);

impl<T> Foo for Y<T> {}
impl HasAssoc for X {
    type Assoc<T> = Y<T>;
}

but I would really like to add that bound in afterwards for abstraction purposes (I want e.g. both HasFooAssoc and HasBarAssoc, and I'd like to have the HasAssoc part factored out, because in the real use case it's more complex).

Are GATs really necessary here?  Can you not use traits with type parameters instead?

I found https://users.rust-lang.org/t/playing-with-non-lifetime-binders/95571 describing a similar problem, for which one workaround was making everything ?Sized. It looks like that allows this case too:
#![feature(non_lifetime_binders)]

trait Foo {}

trait HasAssoc {
    type Assoc<T: ?Sized>;
}

trait HasFooAssoc: for<T> HasAssoc<Assoc<T>: Foo> {}

struct X;
struct Y<T: ?Sized>(Box<T>);

impl<T: ?Sized> Foo for Y<T> {}
impl HasAssoc for X {
    type Assoc<T: ?Sized> = Y<T>;
}
impl HasFooAssoc for X {}

I also see that https://github.com/rust-lang/types-team/issues/81 says:

They should eventually work synergistically with implication predicates, if or when we add support for those (e.g. where for<T: Debug> Self::Assoc<T>: Debug).

So perhaps one day you will just be allowed to write for<T: Sized>.
